# Resizing HDD in ubuntu server 20.04LTS installation

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I have 500GB HDD with windows 10 installed. If i go to Disk Management in windows i see two small partitions and one big 495GB partition in the center. I believe this is where my main windows 10 is installed. Now i'm trying to install ubuntu server 20.04 LTS on this same HDD and make it dual boot. one option i have is to resize my 495GB partition using disk management in windows 10 to 295GB and spare 200GB for ubuntu installation. I like to do this partition resizing in ubuntu installation disk partitioning step. I have tried several times and everytime i end-up losing my windows 10 installation. I can do this in ubuntu desktop installation because GUI makes it easier to resize partition but not getting successful on server installation.

Comment: After installing windows 10 again as it seems you need to start with the live media and let the install do the default setup. It was ask if you want to install beside windows. If it does not you need to note any messages and edit your question.

Comment: Most contributors on here recommend using Windows tools to make changes to Windows partitions.